# How to add the necessary ports to apache?

Tags: lubuntu, apache2

Lubuntu is installed and all runs great - now I want to add apache or lamp. How to proceed?

I need to add all the important ports and the firewall. Besides this I want to install 
the phpmyadmin. Well is this hard to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at all this fairly simple.

```
$ sudo apt-get install apache2 libapache2-mod-php5 php5 phpmyadmin
```

After that you should be all set. If you want to add the ports to the firewall these are port 80/TCP for HTTP and 443/TCP for HTTPS, if you want ssl also do:

```
 $ sudo a2enmod ssl
 $ sudo a2ensite default-ssl
```

And to add to iptables:

```
 $ sudo iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
 $ sudo iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

Not completely sure about the IPtables commands since I usually reload using a config file.

If you have any more problems please let me know.

Kind regards,
Jochen

Comment: thx alot for all the hints: by the way - i do not need root access to run these commands do i!? love to hear from you  greetings

Comment: Yes you need sudo permissions @zero